# Silverlight Security- Sensitive Data

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, security

Silverlight works on client side so putting any sensitive data like connection strings, passwords etc. in the code seems not to be a good thing. I want to build whole web app in Silverlight doing lots of authorization and database quering things. How to make it safe? Any tips&tricks and what things should I avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never developed / used a silverlight app, but I would assume you would use a webservice to broker communication between your app and the database.

This is at least how Flex works.

Edit: This is how Silverlight works as well